# How do I unlock chests with an eyeball on it?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I have come across multiple chests that will not let me open them. They have an eye in the middle which looks at me when I get close.

They look like this:

[image: Chest with an eyeball on it in Hogwarts Legacy]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must cast the Disillusionment charm so that you are invisible to the eyeball, letting you get close and open it. Note that you must cast this at a little bit of a distance (only a few metres) so it doesn't see you coming. You can then get close to the chest whilst invisible and open it.

Comment: I think you just have to break line of sight at a minimum or go far enough away. Was hoping the chest would ignore me if I use disillusionment right in front of it. Couldn't loot until I broke LOS.